# ¿Como enviar solo 5 columnas de un datatable que tiene 20 a un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema que tengo y como siempre muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Necesito pasar un DataTable a un procedimiento almacenado.

Este DataTable contiene 20 columnas de las cuales solo quiero pasar 5. ¿Alguien sabe como pasar solo este numero de columnas y no todas?.

Por el procedimiento almacenado no hay problema ya que el código ya lo tengo lo que me hace falta es solo pasar este numero de columnas.

Aquí coloco mi código.

```
        string path_ArchivoExcel  = HttpContext.Current.Session["fileLocation"].ToString();
        DataTable datos_HojaExcel = new DataTable();
        datos_HojaExcel = HttpContext.Current.Session["dtExcel"] as DataTable;
        datos_HojaExcel.Columns.RemoveAt(2); //Aquí es donde yo elimino las columnas que no necesito pero habrá otro método mejor para esto.
```

Comment: O creas un nuevo datatable con las columnas que quieres, o eliminas del que tienes las columnas que no necesitas. En cualquier caso, debes hacer una seleccion de las columnas necesarias (a no ser que fueran, por ejemplo, las 5 primeras. En ese caso tal vez habría algun otro método)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar un datatable a un procedure entiendo usas `Table-Valued Parameters`

[Table-Valued Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

con lo cual el parametro es del tipo `SqlDbType.Structured`

```
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertCategories", connection);  
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", dataReader);  
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

En ese caso puede usar linq para obtener solo los campos que quieres

```
var result = from row in datos_HojaExcel.AsEnumerable()
              select new {
                  campo1 = row.Field<string>("campo1"),
                  campo2 = row.Field<string>("campo2"),
                  campo3 = row.Field<string>("campo3")
               };

  DataTable dt = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Usando el `CopyToDataTable()` puedes obtener el datatable en base a esos campos que definas en el query linq

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini ¿Sabes como puedo hacer este procedimiento en tres capas considerando mas parametros? Un ejemplo  SP_Actualizar(strin usuario, Datatable dt, string ruta_Archivo).

Comment: no entiendo que tienen que ver las capas con la cantidad de parametros, se supone que los valores los pasas en el datatable y queda definido por la tabla a la cual mapea el Structured

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini disculpa si no me especifique bien, me refería al procedimiento almacenado. ¿Como puedo hacer el procedimiento almacenado que ademas de pasar un DataTable pase otros dos parametros? Ejemplo SP_Actualizar(string Usuario, DataTable  dt, string ruta_Archivo)

Comment: ehh definiendo los parametros normalmente y pasando estos en la collecion Parameters del command